# Opening a URL programmatically in oXygen from a website

Tags: oxygenxml

I'm looking to create a link on my website that would open a url in oXygen.  This will only be for developers, so someone with oXygen installed and configured properly.  This only needs to work on MacOS.

The url is for a particular data source connection defined in oXygen that opens the resource in eXist-db.  When opened directly in oXygen, a sample of the url is `oxygen:/eXist-db wmm$eXist-db wmm/db/pdfstyles/lists/1169496.xsl`.  I can open the resource from the command line with `open edit-in-oxygen:oxygen:/eXist-db\ wmm\$eXist-db\ wmm/db/pdfstyles/lists/1169496.xsl`.

What are my options in how to programmatically make this happen when clicking on a link in my website?  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Linking to my reply on the Oxygen XML forum: https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/post73206.html#p73206

Comment: That is pretty easy and does accomplish my major goal.  Clicking it would be nicer, but dragging is acceptable.  Thank you.